# Need a delay between 2 function which have set time out in each

Tags: jquery, delay, settimeout, intervals

I have  2 functions abc() and def(). both are having settimeout function. they are called from parent xyz() function. Initially abc() should be called then after the abc animation def() functionality should be invoked.
Problem: Both the functions are called one after the other but there is no delay between them.both the settimeout are working simultaneously.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
function abc() {
    y = y + 5;
    if (y < 150)
        $('#avatar').css('bottom', y + 'px');
        interval12 = setTimeout(up, 150);
    } else if (y == 150) {
        clearTimeout(interval12);
        console.log("hello1");
    }
}

function def() {
    x = x + 5;
    if (x < newleftmove) {
        $('#avatar').css('left', x + 'px');

        interval1 = setTimeout(movetopLeft, 150, function () {
            afterleft
        });
    } else if (x == newleftmove) {
        clearTimeout(interval1);
        console.log("hello");
    }
}

function xyz() {
    abc();
    def();
}
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation to what I think you were going for, but you have a syntax error: missing `{` after `if (y < 150)`

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using jQuery for your animations?

Comment: yes i'm not supposed to use jquery animation since animation wont give the required effect.i have to settimeout so that there will be a delay in each movement. jquery animation is too smooth.

Comment: This is not an answer but the way you are doing this is insane. CSS Animations, jQuery animations and the Promise pattern all exist to solve the problem you are talking about.

Comment: oops .. i'm sorry but i erased the brace by mistake.. if(y <150) {..

Comment: @JasonP could you please help resolve the issue... i would be appreciated.

Comment: In that case, you will need to implement callbacks or deferred objects in `abc()` and `def()` to notify the caller when they have finished their work.

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery

I would suggest looking at jQuery, or similar, to do the animation in `abc()` and use the callback to trigger `def()`. Even if you need pauses you can do that with jQuery. Just animate with no delay and use the `delay()` method to delay before the next animation step.

```
someEl.animate( { top: 100 }, 10 ).delay( 150 ).animate( { top: 200 }, 10, def );
```

### CSS transition

Another approach is to use CSS transitions for the animation and trigger `def()` on the `transitionend` event ...

Example css:

```
.before_animation{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: top 2s;
}

.animated{
  top: 100px;
}
```

To trigger the animation you add the `.animated` class to the element, that already has the `.before_animation` class.

You then need to listen for the end event:

```
el.addEventListener( "transitionend" def );
```

or with jQuery:

```
$(el).on( 'transitionend', def );
```

### Final thoughts

As others have pointed out in the comments. This is a solved problem. Use the tools available instead of hacking your own. No matter if you want to target legacy browsers or modern browsers or both there is a better way than `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Another approach is to use CSS transitions for the animation and trigger def() on the transitionend event ... could you please elaborate on this. can u give me a basic syntax. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a prototype for this, just insert this code in you file :

```
//@Author Karl-André Gagnon
if(!Function.prototype.delay){
    Function.prototype.delay = function(time, target){
        var fn = this;
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
        setTimeout(function(){
            fn.apply(target, args);
        }, time)
    }
}
```

This function need 2 arguments to work: the time and the `this` reference.

Check the example : http://jsfiddle.net/UL6RM/

Use it in you code like that :

```
abc();
def.delay(150, null); //150 = time; null = this (unused)
```

Comment: @user3044827 My pleasure, but please, i can't prevent you from removing it, but if you use this code, i would be glad if you keep the `@author` comment.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I'm concerned your `abc` and `def` should be recursively called after every 150 millisecond. you have to wait until the first animation is done and then call the next step. you can try this:

```
function abc() {
    y = y + 5;
    if (y < 150) {
        $('#avatar').css('bottom', y + 'px');
        interval12 = setTimeout(up, 150);
    } else if (y == 150) {
        clearTimeout(interval12);
        if (typeof (arguments.callee.nextStep) == "function") {
            arguments.callee.nextStep.call(this);
        }
        console.log("hello1");
    }
}


function def() {
    x = x + 5;
    if (x < newleftmove) {
        $('#avatar').css('left', x + 'px');

        interval1 = setTimeout(movetopLeft, 150, function () {
            afterleft
        });
    } else if (x == newleftmove) {
        clearTimeout(interval1);
        if (typeof (arguments.callee.nextStep) == "function") {
            arguments.callee.nextStep.call(this);
        }
        console.log("hello");
    }
}

//It could be you nex step after def is called
function geh() {
    //do whatever you want
}
function xyz() {
    abc.nextStep = def;
    def.nextStep = geh;
    abc();
}
```